# How train a classifier on different feature types together? Like String,numeric,Categorical, timestamp etc

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am a newbie in field of machine Learning. I have taken Udacity's "Introduction to Machine Learning" course. So I know running basic classifiers using sklearn and python. But all the classifiers they taught in the course was trained on a single data type.

I have a problem wherein I want to classify a code commit as "clean" or "buggy".
I have a feature set which contains String data (like name of person), Categorical data (say "clean" vs "buggy"), numeric data (like no. of commits) and timestamp data (like time of commit). How can I train a classifier based on these three features simultaneously. Lets assuming that I plan on using a Naive Bayes classifier and sklearn. Please Help!

I am trying to implement the [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2848/2c0fb5ad5a83c749178d2538bd7e8eb487fe.pdf). Any help would really be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many machine learning classifiers like logistic regression, random forest, decision trees and SVM work fine with both continuous and categorical features. My guess is that you have two paths to follow. The first one is data **pre-processing**. For example, convert all string/cateogorical data (name of a person) to integers or you can use **ensemble learning**.

Ensemble learning is when you combine different classifiers (each one dealing with one kind of heterogeneous feature) using majority vote, for example, so they can find a consensus in classification. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Victor. I've been working on the problem but couldn't find anything substantial. I am using scikit-learn library for it. Can you help me out with some example snippet as to how to use different types of features together in a classifier? Thanks in advance